# Does the Genius ability boost all skills involving INT or just INT rolls?

Tags: iron-kingdoms

In the RPG Iron Kingdoms there is an archetype ability called Genius which says all INT rolls are boosted. Does that mean all skills involving INT are boosted, or only INT rolls themselves?

Answer (score 5):

All rolls based on INT, be it skill checks or INT checks.

The same goes for **Hyper Perception** (for PER checks), and **Deft** (For AGI checks).

[Official Source](http://privateerpressforums.com/showthread.php?120724-Genius-Hyper-Per-Deft-etc)

Comment: Also my friend says it only boosts INT rolls iow rolls that don't fall under any specific skill in which case are *insert attribute here* rolls.  Any comment?

Comment: Your friend is wrong, sorry. I linked a post from the main developer of the game.